# Como criar componentes a partir de um outro componente base

Tags: react, web-component

A ideia é criar um componente para cada tipo de entrada, por exemplo, `InputPassword` para `<input type="password">`, porém, visando a reutilização de código, a maioria desses componentes tem uma base igual, todos tem uma `<div>` como container, possuem um elemento `<input>` e um elemento `<label>`, então criei uma classe base:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Input extends Component {
    constructor(props, context, data) {
        this.data = data;

        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`input-field col ${this.data.size || ''}`}>
                {this.data.leftIcon ? <i className={`${this.data.leftIcon} prefix left`}></i> : ''}

                <input
                    type={this.data.type}
                    value={this.data.value}
                    id={`input-${this.data.type}-${Input.prototype.counter}`}
                    className={this.data.validate ? 'validate' : ''}
                />

                <label for={`input-${Input.prototype.counter}`}>
                    {this.data.label || ''}
                </label>

                {this.data.rightIcon ? <i className={`${this.data.rightIcon} prefix right`}></i> : ''}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Input.prototype.counter = Input.prototype.counter || 0;
```

E um componente para senhas:

```
import React from 'react';

import Input from './Input';

export default class InputPassword extends Input {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context, {
            type: 'password',
            value: '',
            size: this.props.size,
            placeholder: 'Digite sua senha',
            label: 'Senha',
            disabled: false,
            rightIcon: 'fas fa-eye',
            validate: true,
            helperText: '',
            successText: 'Senha válida',
            errorText: 'Senha inválida',
        });
    }
}
```

Assim é possível fazer pequenas alterações na base sem ter que alterar em diversos lugares, porém ao tentar usar esse component (`InputPassword`) recebo o erro:

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/components/Inputs/InputPassword.js
>
> Line 3:  'Input' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
>
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Observação: estou usando o MaterializeCSS (v1) e o FontAwesome (v5.5)

Comment: A "herança" de componente desta forma pode ser tratada com [high order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), que são basicamente funções que recebem um componente e retornam este componente melhorado. Existem alguns exemploscomo [este aqui](https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/handle-loadings-in-react-by-using-higher-order-components-2ee8de9c3deb) que acho que podem dar uma luz no que você quer fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de atingir este resultado com React é utilizando composição (por sinal, herança de componentes não é recomendado no React).

O que você pode fazer, de maneira simplificada:

```
class Input extends React.Component{
    render(){
         return(
             <div>
                 <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                 <input type={this.props.inputType} />
             </div>
         )
    }
}

class InputText extends React.Component {
     render(){
          return <Input inputType='text' label='Texto' />
     }
}
// exemplo com functional-stateless components
const InputPass = props => <Input inputType='password' label='Senha' />
```

Mais referências: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html